# Замена цвета главной формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть главная форма. При нажатии на "Параметры" открывается другая форма с параметрами где нужно при помощи radiobutton поменять цвет главной формы.
Почему-то не работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public partial class Options : Form
{
    public Options()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }




    private void rbRed_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm main = new MainForm();
        main.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Главная форма

```
private void tsmiOptions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Проблема именно в написании кода. Чтобы взаимодействовать с формами

Comment: Где код? Добавьте пожалуйста код в Ваш вопрос. А то так вам телепатически помогать не смогут.

Comment: Вы можете вызывать вторую форму с помощью калбэк и после изменения отправлять изменение обратно

Comment: Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, есть простейший класс настроек

```
public class Settings
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SettingsChanged;
    private void RaiseSettingsChanged() => 
              SettingsChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);       
    private Color _mainFormColor ;
    public Color MainFormColor {
        get => _mainFormColor;      
        set {
            _mainFormColor = value;
            RaiseSettingsChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Форма для их отображения

```
public class Options : Form
{
    private Settings _settings;

    public Options(Settings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;   
        var colors = new[] {Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Gray};
        int shift = 0;
        foreach(var color in colors)
        {
            var rb = new RadioButton() {Top = shift};
            shift+=20;
            rb.Text = color.ToString();
            rb.CheckedChanged += (sender, args) => 
                { if (rb.Checked) _settings.MainFormColor = color;};
            this.Controls.Add(rb);
        }
    }   
}
```

Основная форма

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    private Settings _settings;     
    public MainForm()
    {
        _settings = new Settings();
        _settings.SettingsChanged+= (sender, args) => 
                 this.BackColor = _settings.MainFormColor;
        var bt = new Button() {Text = "Options"};
        bt.Click+= (sender, args) => new Options(_settings).ShowDialog();
        this.Controls.Add(bt);
    }
}
```

И результат

[image: ...]

Answer (score 0):

Как я решил бы это вопрос:
Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        //...
    }
    //Создаём класс DataTransfer
    public class DataTransfer
    {
        public object[] data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    namespace WindowsFormsApp
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DataTransfer dataTransfer = new DataTransfer { data = new object[] { "зеленый\n" } };
                //Передаём объект dataTransfer первой формы во вторую форму
                Form2 form2 = new Form2(dataTransfer);
                form2.ShowDialog();
// После можно создать функцию сравнения текста и применять этот цвет и вызывать ее
            }
        }
    }
```

Form2.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        DataTransfer dataTransfer;
        public Form2(DataTransfer _dataTransfer)
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            //Чтобы вторая форма могла принять объект необходимо подправить её конструктор
            dataTransfer = _dataTransfer;
        }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Изменяем dataTransfer.
            dataTransfer.data[0] = dataTransfer.data[0].ToString() + "красный";
            Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Data Transfer может не только с текстом работать но и сразу с цветом, можете почитать на сайте(msdn вроде так, давно не пишу на шарпе). Это очень наглядный пример как передать параметр между формами